# Adjusting page elements position layout using twitter bootstrap specific to mobile devices

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am making a search box which looks like this on a desktop browser:

[image]

And it currently looks like this on a Mobile browser:

[image]

The code for the UI elements in question looks like the following:

```
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="adult">
    <h4>Adult tickets</h4>
    <form class="navbar-form" role="search" action="/search" method="get">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for an event" name="q" id="q">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <div class="btn-group" role="group">

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle form-control" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span data-bind="label">All Adult Categories</span>
                    <input type="hidden" name="category" id="category" value="All Adult Categories">
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu menu-scroll" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">All Adult Categories</a></li>
                    <% @adultCategories.each do |category| %>
                    <li><a href="#"><%= category.name %></a></li>
                    <% end %>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

I need to tidy up the mobile browser view. I think it would look best if the search **text box was on its own line** - and consumed its own line on a mobile, and then the category dropdown box can be on a **line right underneath** the search term box with the actual search button to the right hand side of it.

Essentially breaking the 3 UI elements, the search text box, the button dropdown and the search button into 2 lines, the first search term on its own, and the second line split between the category dropdown and the search button. I don't particularly want to adjust the look for the desktop version - so is there a way I can do this using the CSS i apply for mobile devices - or is there something I can change in the DOM to get this behaviour but leave the look as it is on the desktop version? Any other ideas would be welcome

Many thanks!

Comment: Is that the entire html for your inputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to separate out your search box and dropdownmenu/button using bootstrap's columns. That leaves upto bootstrap to decide, that if the elements are unable to fit into the screen, it stacks them up. Made a small fiddle for your code -

http://jsfiddle.net/ve1uqmLh/1/

```
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="adult">
<h4>Adult tickets</h4>
<form class="navbar-form" role="search" action="/search" method="get">
<div class="input-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for an event" name="q" id="q">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle form-control" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span data-bind="label">All Adult Categories</span>
                    <input type="hidden" name="category" id="category" value="All Adult Categories">
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu menu-scroll" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">All Adult Categories</a></li>
                    <% @adultCategories.each do |category| %>
                    <li><a href="#"><%= category.name %></a></li>
                    <% end %>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Fantastic - thank you very much! I thought it would be something like this but I was not sure!

Comment: Almost what I need - however can you explain why when I add the second input field - which should always be sat directly underneath the initial query text box it seems to add padding to the right hand side : http://jsfiddle.net/ve1uqmLh/2/

Comment: I see that you have added another col-sm-5 class inside the same row class. Actually bootstrap is a 12 column grid system and you cannot have more cols than that in a row. That is why I added col-sm-5 and col-sm-7 to divide up the row. I would recommend going through this link - getbootstrap.com/css/#grid. It will give you a lot better understanding about laying out controls.

Comment: aha - that is useful - thank you. I have now tried this : http://jsfiddle.net/ve1uqmLh/4/ - basically closed the row, and created a new input group row div outside of my col-sm-5 but its not on a seperate row...which is odd considering I have asked it to be.

Comment: Ok - all fixed - I appreciate your help!